# JPA mapping: "QuerySyntaxException: foobar is not mapped..."

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jpa

I've been playing around with a very simple JPA example and am trying to tweak it to an existing database.  But I can't get past this error.  (Below.)  It just has to be some simple thing I am not seeing.

```
org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: FooBar is not mapped [SELECT r FROM FooBar r]
  org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.util.SessionFactoryHelper.requireClassPersister(SessionFactoryHelper.java:180)
  org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.FromElementFactory.addFromElement(FromElementFactory.java:110)
  org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.FromClause.addFromElement(FromClause.java:93)
```

In the DocumentManager class below (a simple servlet, as that is my target goal) does two things:

1. insert a row
2. return all rows

The insertion works perfectly--all is good there.  The problem is with the retrieval.  I've tried all sorts of values for the `Query q = entityManager.createQuery` parameters, but no luck, and I've tried variously more explicate annotations of the class (like column types), all without success.

Please save me from myself.  I'm certain it is something small.  My inexperience with JPA is preventing me from going any farther.

**My ./src/ch/geekomatic/jpa/FooBar.java file:**

```
@Entity
@Table( name = "foobar" )
public class FooBar {
    @Id 
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY) 
    @Column(name="id")
    private int id;

    @Column(name="rcpt_who")
    private String rcpt_who;

    @Column(name="rcpt_what")
    private String rcpt_what;

    @Column(name="rcpt_where")
    private String rcpt_where;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getRcpt_who() {
        return rcpt_who;
    }
    public void setRcpt_who(String rcpt_who) {
        this.rcpt_who = rcpt_who;
    }

    //snip...the other getters/setters are here
}
```

**My ./src/ch/geekomatic/jpa/DocumentManager.java class**

```
public class DocumentManager extends HttpServlet {
    private EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory( "ch.geekomatic.jpa" );

    protected void tearDown() throws Exception {
        entityManagerFactory.close();
    }

   @Override
   public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException, ServletException {
       FooBar document = new FooBar();
       document.setRcpt_what("my what");
       document.setRcpt_who("my who");

       persist(document);

       retrieveAll(response);
   }

   public void persist(FooBar document) {
       EntityManager entityManager = entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();
       entityManager.getTransaction().begin();
       entityManager.persist( document );
       entityManager.getTransaction().commit();
       entityManager.close();
   }

    public void retrieveAll(HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
        EntityManager entityManager = entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();
        entityManager.getTransaction().begin();

        //  *** PROBLEM LINE ***
        Query q = entityManager.createQuery( "SELECT r FROM foobar r", FooBar.class );
        List<FooBar> result = q.getResultList();

        for ( FooBar doc : result ) {
            response.getOutputStream().write(event.toString().getBytes());
            System.out.println( "Document " + doc.getId()  );
        }
        entityManager.getTransaction().commit();
        entityManager.close();
    }
}
```

**The {tomcat-home}/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/classes/METE-INF/persistance.xml file**

```
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd"
    version="2.0">

<persistence-unit name="ch.geekomatic.jpa">
    <description>test stuff for dc</description>

    <class>ch.geekomatic.jpa.FooBar</class>

    <properties>
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver"   value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url"      value="jdbc:mysql://svr:3306/test" />
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user"     value="wafflesAreYummie" />
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="poniesRock" />

        <property name="hibernate.show_sql"     value="true" />
        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create" />
    </properties>

</persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

**The MySQL table description:**

```
mysql> describe foobar;
+------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field      | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id         | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| rcpt_what  | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| rcpt_where | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| rcpt_who   | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Answer (score 209, accepted):

JPQL *mostly* is case-insensitive. One of the things that is case-sensitive is Java entity names. Change your query to:

```
"SELECT r FROM FooBar r"
```

Comment: So, to the class name and not the table name?

Comment: Yes. Though it looks like sql, your executing JPA Query Language; so you're selecting from Entities, not from tables.

Comment: You gotta be kidding me! I just spent 2 hours ripping config files apart, checking classpaths and re-engineering build files. I read your post and changed "tableName" to "TableName" and it worked!

Comment: I spent way too many hours searching for this answer. Drinks on me if I ever find you, internet person. :)

Comment: i don't know how to thank you in words! i'm sobbing

Comment: If you have used Enity annotation in the entity class, use the entity name instead of the class name.

Answer (score 15):

There is also another possible source of this error. **In some J2EE / web containers** (in my experience under Jboss 7.x and Tomcat 7.x) You have to add each class You want to use as a hibernate Entity into the file **persistence.xml** as

`<class>com.yourCompanyName.WhateverEntityClass</class>`

In case of jboss this concerns every entity class (local - i.e. within the project You are developing or in a library). In case of Tomcat 7.x this concerns only entity classes within libraries.

Answer (score 9):

You have declared your Class as:

```
@Table( name = "foobar" )
public class FooBar {
```

You need to write the Class Name for the search.
from `FooBar`

Answer (score 4):

I got the same error while using other one entity, He was annotating the class wrongly by using the table name inside the @Entity annotation without using the @Table annotation

The correct format should be

```
@Entity //default name similar to class name 'FooBar' OR @Entity( name = "foobar" ) for differnt entity name
@Table( name = "foobar" ) // Table name 
public class FooBar{
```

Comment: I just did this accidentally and couldn't find the error cause, thank you for saving my time

Answer (score 0):

Not related to your issue but once I faced JPA mapping: "QuerySyntaxException: foobar is not mapped... issue because I added

```
@Entity(name="foo")
class Foobar{
...
}
```

and tried to refer Foobar

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Could also be the annotation provider, for newer versions of hibernate they use jakarta.persistence.* and not javax.persistence.*

HOPE IT DOESN'T TAKE HOURS OF HEAD WALLING TO FIGURE THAT OUT