# Java: How to resolve class is not mapped exception in Hibernate Query Language?

Tags: java, hibernate, hql, hibernate-mapping

While executing the delete query, I am getting "class is not mapped", while I have mapped in `hibernate.cfg.xml`.

[image]

Comment: Don't show a screenshot. Add the error as text to your question. Further, if you had taken a single search you would have found an SO question. Marking this as a duplicate of that question btw.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JPA mapping: "QuerySyntaxException: foobar is not mapped..."](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8230309/jpa-mapping-querysyntaxexception-foobar-is-not-mapped)

Comment: i m using table name instead of class name thats why i got this error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not to use a table name in the HQL query, like `plan_attribute`, but a class name, like `PlanAttribute`. The same for the property `plan_id`.

Comment: ie. pojoClass Name .. which i have generated form Hibernate Reverse Engineering

Comment: then why it not showing any error when i am going to execute select query update query with the table name istead of classname ?

Comment: @javaignite.com Probably, you use SQL (not HQL) for such queries.